# Giving an original array and a new array that each element's value indicates the count of elements on the left that are bigger

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, performance

Giving an array, say [4,2,1,3,5], based on this array, we have a new array, which each number shows the count of elements on its left that are bigger than itself, which is [0,1,2,1,0]. Now write a function with given input of [0,1,2,1,0], return the original array. The range of array is 1 ~ n (n is the size of the array, you can assume all numbers in the original array are consecutive if sorted)

Now to recover the original array, I have tried a way to solve the problem by iterating through the range of array from the end to the front like this:

*My approach*:

say the range is 1 ~ 5, the original array would be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] if sorted. Iterate from the end to the beg,

so first 5, there is no element can be bigger than 5, so its maximum count of bigger elements would be 0, then 4 would have 1 as its maximum count of bigger elements, 3 to 2, etc. Store the key-value pairs into an object.

Now iterating through the input from back to front,

1. 0  -> 5
2. 1 -> can be 4, 3, or 2
3. 2 -> can be either 3, 2, or 1
4. 1 -> any number bigger than the first one.
5. 0 -> (can be anything, since 5 is taken, so it can be either 1, 2, 3, or 4)

Simply to map each element of the input as value to its key from the map is not enough. What would be an intuitive way to approach this with optimal performance? (avoiding O(n ^2) if possible.)

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: @4castle I edited the post with my original approach which didn't seem to work.

Comment: Make sure to credit this web site when you turn in your assignment. Academic dishonesty is considered a serious offense at most institutions.

Comment: @RaymondChen Just want to clarify, this is not for academic assignment. I am only asking for ideas of a better approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially make an AVL Tree from numbers 1 to n.

Start from rear i.e. at nth index (considering 1 based index).

Now the high level outline level of the algorithm should look like this:

```
1. At any ith index, say the number in array(not the originial array) is j
2. Search the number which is at (i-j)th position in your AVL tree(This can be done in O(logn) time. Comment if you need more explanation on this)
3. The element in the AVL tree is your required element. Delete that element from AVL tree.(O(logn))
```

So the total complexity would be O(nlogn).

**Walkthrough**

Initially the tree will contain all 5 elements.

1. You start at index 5(1-based indexing). Element is 0, i.e. i=5, j=0. So 5th largest element which is 5.
2. Now the tree contains four elements 1,2, 3, and 4. i=4, j=1. So 4-1 i..e 3rd largest element which is 3 in this case.
3. i=3, j=2. (3-2)rd largest element is 1 since the tree contains (1, 2, 4).

And so on.

**Using Tree to find the ith largest number**

We can do this by, storing the count of number of nodes in left subtree at the root node. So consider a tree, having elements 1, 2, 3,4 and 5 and tree structure as following:

```
        4(3)
      /     \
     3(1)   5(0)
     /   \
    1(0)  2(0)
```

At root, number 4 is the value and the number in round bracket has the number of nodes in left subtree.

While constructing(insertion and deletion too) the tree, we can maintain the count.

Now, to find the ith node, say we want suppose 3rd nodes in the given tree. We start with the root, it says it has 3 elements smaller than it to the left so we move to left. Now the root i.e. 3 has 1 smaller left element which is less than 3(ith element) so we move to right of it. Subtract 1(the left count)+1(the root itself) out of 3. Now the root is 2 we want 1st element, the left count is 0. Hence the 1st element of the subtree rooted at 2 is 2.

Basic pseudocode is below:

```
while(true){
  count  = root->leftCount;
  if((count+1)<i){
     //move to right
     i-=(count+1);
     root = root->right;
  }
  else if(i==(count+1)){
     //root is the ith node
     break;
  } else{
     //move to the levft
     root=root->left

  }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain step 2 in your high level outline?

Comment: @mikuya707 Edited the answer, its in detail now. Reach out if misunderstanding in any part.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) and use the value as negative index for generating the original array.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    countLeft = [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
    result = countLeft.reduceRight(function (r, a) {
        return array.splice(array.length - 1 - a, 1).concat(r);
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Shorter version with ES6 and reverse base array.

```js
var array = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    countLeft = [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
    indices = array.map((_, i) => i),
    result = [];

countLeft.forEach(a => {
    result.unshift(array[indices[a]]);
    indices = indices.filter((_, i) => i !== a);
});

console.log(result);
```

At last a proposal with complexity between O(n*(n-1)/2) and O(n).

This version uses a lazy array with progressive reduction of the length for every iteration. At the end, the offset array has zero elements.

```js
var array = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    countLeft = [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
    result = [],
    length = array.length;

countLeft.forEach((offset => (offset.length = countLeft.length, a => {
    var i = offset[a] || 0;
    result.unshift(array[i + a]);
    offset.length--;
    while (i < offset.length) {
        offset[i] = (offset[i] || 0) + 1;
        i++;
    }
}))([]));

console.log(result);
```

A linear version, heavily inspired by the [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38296706/1447675) of [Oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529630/oriol)

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    countLeft = [0, 1, 2, 1, 0],
    swap = [],
    i = 0,
    l,
    temp;

while (i < countLeft.length) {
    l = countLeft[i];
    while (l) {
        swap.push(i + l - countLeft[i]);
        l--;
    }
    i++;
}
i = swap.length;
while (i--) {
    temp = array[swap[i]];
    array[swap[i]] = array[swap[i] - 1];
    array[swap[i] - 1] = temp;
}

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Can you please explain your algorithm. It would help.

Comment: Are you sure `splice` is `O(1)`? Otherwise, how do you achieve `O(n)`?

Comment: @Oriol, i am not sure.

Comment: I suppose its O(n^2) for the algorithm.

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't know what implementations do, but I think `splice(i,1)` is probably `O(n-i)`. Then it's an average of `O(n/2)`, so the total is `O(n^2/2) = O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. See inline comments for a brief description of this method.

```
var a = [0,1,2,1,0],
    n, b = [], res = [];

// build b = [5,4,3,2,1]
// we use this array to keep track of values to be pushed in res[],
// sorted in descending order
for(n = a.length; n > 0; n--) {
  b.push(n);
}

// for each element of a, starting from the end:
// find correct value in b and remove it from b
while(a.length) {
  res.push(b.splice(a.pop(), 1)[0]);
}

res = res.reverse();
console.log(res);
```

Output:

```
[4, 2, 1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: What wouldbe the complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: I've added the complexity in my answer. (NB : you can see it as O(2n) because of the 2 loops, but O(2n) = O(n) anyway.)

Comment: I suppose, splice will take worst case O(n) time, which makes it O(n^2).

Comment: You seem to misunderstand big-O. It's not a count of how many loops there are, it's a count of how many times an O(1) operation occurs. The statements inside the second loop are O(n^2) from the shift and splice which require modifying every element in the array, so it's more like O(n^3)

Comment: @4castle : I did miss the hidden complexity behind splice(). Answer edited to remove the complexity of unshift(), assuming that reverse() is O(n) as well which should be the case. All in all, it's still O(n^2) because of the splice().

Answer (score 0):

I propose an approach based on a custom sort, based on mergesort:

1. Split the array of inversions into two halves
2. Sort each part recursively, from greatest to lowest, maintaining stability
3. Merge the two parts

The difference with mergesort is the merge part. If we choose the `j`-th element of right part instead of the `i`-th of the left one, it will advance some elements, and therefore its number of inversions must be reduced by that amount.

Like mergesort, the complexity is `O(n log n)`

```js
function undoInversions(inversions) {
  function reorder(arr, from=0, to=arr.length) {
    // Based on a stable decreasing mergesort
    if(from >= to) return [];                // Unusual base case
    if(to === from + 1) return [arr[from]];  // Base case
    var m = Math.floor((from + to)/2);
    var l = reorder(arr, from, m),           // Left recursive call
        r = reorder(arr, m, to),             // Right recursive call
        ret = [], i=0, j=0;
    while(i < l.length && j < r.length) {    // Merge
      if(r[j].value - l.length + i >= l[i].value) {
        r[j].value -= l.length - i;          // Reduce number of inversions
        ret.push(r[j++]);
      } else {
        ret.push(l[i++]);
      }
    }
    while(i < l.length) ret.push(l[i++]);    // Merge remaining, if any
    while(j < r.length) ret.push(r[j++]);    // Merge remaining, if any
    return ret;
  }
  var array = new Array(inversions.length);
  reorder(inversions.map(function(inv, idx) {
    return {value: inv, originalIndex: idx}; // Keep track of indices
  })).forEach(function(obj, idx) {
    if(obj.value !== 0) throw 'Invalid input';
    array[obj.originalIndex] = idx + 1;      // Invert the permutation
  });
  return array;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(undoInversions([0,1,2,1,0])));
```

Here is an example to understand how it works:

```
[0,1,2,1,0]  ~  [4,2,1,3,5]
  ⤩               ⤧
[0,0,2,1,0]  ~  [2,4,1,3,5]
    ⤩               ⤧
[0,1,0,1,0]  ~  [2,1,4,3,5]
  ⤩               ⤧
[0,0,0,1,0]  ~  [1,2,4,3,5]
      ⤩               ⤧
[0,0,0,0,0] ——→ [1,2,3,4,5]
```

That is, each array of inversions corresponds to a permutation. We apply a permutation `σ` which transforms the input to the array of inversions `[0,0,0,0,0]`, which corresponds to the permutation `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Since we kept track of the original indices, now we only need the to apply `σ⁻¹` to `[1,2,3,4,5]` in order to get the permutation corresponding to the input.

Comment: Can you please briefly explain the approach would help to non JS programmers.

Comment: @AkashdeepSaluja I have fixed my idea, and included the explanation.

Comment: i don't get the complexity. a *single* sort is always in the best cas O(n log n) and multiple sort are more worst.

Comment: @NinaScholz The complexity is `O(n log n)` because it's a recursion `T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + n`, and according to the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) this means `T(n) = Θ(n log n)`. It's the same as [mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Analysis). I don't understand what you mean with single or multiple sort.

Comment: i think it is right for one merge sort, but you call it more than one time.

Comment: I only call it once. Then it calls itself recursive twice, but each call only takes into account half input. So `T(n)` costs `T(n/2)` for the first recursive call, `T(n/2)` for the second one, and `n` for the final merge.

Comment: [Empirical proof it's really `n log n`](https://jsfiddle.net/x4dnhxvo/)